# How to show Icon in the end of text in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to show Icon in the end of text even if the text is ellipsis.

[image]

[image: what i want]

this is my code

```
Text.rich(
                TextSpan(
                  children: [
                    const TextSpan(
                      text:
                          "Singapore & Shenzhen & Guangzhou & Beijing ni hao hao",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 28,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    WidgetSpan(
                      child: Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 7),
                        child: SvgPicture.asset(
                          R.triangle_down_fill,
                          package: R.package,
                          width: 18,
                          height: 18,
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                maxLines: 2,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                softWrap: true,
              )
```

it works well in first situation but the second situation not, The icon is removed by the text.

So what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your widgets with `Wrap` widget

```
Wrap(
      children: [Text.rich(
                TextSpan(
                  children: [
                    const TextSpan(
                      text:
                          "Singapore & Shenzhen & Guangzhou & Beijing ni hao hao",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 28,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    WidgetSpan(
                      child: Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 7),
                        child: SvgPicture.asset(
                          R.triangle_down_fill,
                          package: R.package,
                          width: 18,
                          height: 18,
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                maxLines: 2,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                softWrap: true,
              ),
        Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down_circle)
    ],
    ),
```